# IndexOutOfRangeException with DataTable.Select

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, datatable

I have this code:

```
private void comboBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var price = dt.Select("desc = '" + comboBox2.Text + "'", "price ASC");

    textBox9.Text = price[0][2].ToString();
}
```

dt is a datatable holding stock items in rows like so: id,desc,price

The code it self works fine when I choose an item from the combobox (populated from dt) but if I start to type in the combobox I get this error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

How do I do the lookup only when the combobox is completed with one of the contained items?

Much love. :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is fired always when the user(ot the program) changes the text, even if he has not yet finished typing. Since you are comparing with `=` the text must match `desc` completely. Therefore `DataTable.Select` returns no rows which causes the exception when you try to access the first row of the array.

Change the filter to match also substrings. You can prevent the error by checking if the array contains rows:

1)

```
var price = dt.Select("desc LIKE '*" + comboBox2.Text + "*'", "price ASC");
```

2)

```
if(price.Any())
    textBox9.Text = price[0][2].ToString();
```

Sidenote, i find LINQ-To-DataTable more readable:

```
var foundRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                let desc = row.Field<string>("desc")
                where desc.Contains(comboBox2.Text)
                select row;
DataRow firstMatch = foundRows.FirstOrDefault();
if(firstMatch != null)
{
    textBox9.Text = firstMatch.Field<string>(2);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is good idea to make Like check because this will execute on every letter change and in the end the value in the textbox will be equal to the last letter which find a row. Anyway, I didn't know about Any() method, thanks about that +1 from me !

Comment: @mybirthname: you might be right, the `Like`-check is less efficient even if this is not a database query. OP could also use `...comboBox2.Text + "*...` or `desc.StartsWith` to get only rows where the column begins with the entered text. However, i just wanted to provide a solution for the no-match issue until the user types. OP should prevent the exception anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In your case var price doesn't return anything, because written string by the use is not data Table. This code should help.

```
        if (price != null && price.Count() > 0)
        {
            textBox9.Text = price[0][2].ToString();
        }
```

Other case is to make the combobox type dropdown list and the user should set the input from the datatable only.

Also like Tim Schmelter said this Text_Changed event will be executed on every letter written by the user. Be aware of that !

P.S Be aware to write the column names, don't use indexes for the column names this is not good practice !

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the code in try catch block then the exception that is being thrown will be handled silently and when the correct input is given valid answer will be shown, you can use the code like this:-

```
private void comboBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var price = dt.Select("desc = '" + comboBox2.Text + "'", "price ASC");

        textBox9.Text = price[0][2].ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception xyz)
    {}
}
```